# Progress info on client side?

Tags: java

I've a Servlet which is used to generate and download file using **ServletOutputStream**. It's working well. But the Servlet some time take several seconds to process request depending on size of the file.

My questions is I want show the some progress information to client side. How do I do it?

Comment: do you need to show real, accurate progress?  Or just provide visual clues to the user that it might be a few seconds, i.e. a spinner would work fine here.

Comment: Visual clues is enough! but how do I implement it?

Comment: You just need a javascript framework with that widget . . .

Answer (score 1):

This comes with any good Javascript toolkit, like jquery for instance.  They have a progress bar.

http://jqueryui.com/

http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/